# Google pub/sub (gmail) is emitting events for revoked tokens that we should not have access to

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

This seems to be a bug with Google pub/sub. Can someone from the Google team confirm why this is happening?

The steps to reproduce are as follows:

1. Subscribe a gmail inbox to pub/sub
2. We receive events every time the inbox is updated, as expected
3. User revokes access from their google settings

**Actual result:** We are still receiving all events (email address, historyId) for revoked refresh/access tokens.

**Expected result:** we do not receive events for users who have revoked their refresh/access tokens.

Firstly we believe this is a bug. 
If it is not, we would like to see some confirmation from the Google team as we cannot find docs to confirm this. And if so, how you recommend we deal with potentially billions of events per minute, this is almost like a DDoS at scale.

Apologies in advance if there are in fact docs that we cannot find.
Many thanks

Comment: I think you are referring to [**`stop()`**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/stop). This will stop receiving updates on a mailbox and all new notifications should stop within a few minutes. Revoking tokens will not stop them from receiving updates on a mailbox. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thanks, but that endpoint says it requires authorization. If the user has revoked access, how can we call stop() ?

Comment: I have the same issue, even if `stop()` is called, or the 7 days of expiration of exceeded (pub/sub subscription), I still continue to receive mailbox updates for some users.